# How can I keep a full-screen Chrome Flash player when Chrome loses focus? 13.04

Tags: google-chrome, flash

When I use a Flash video that has a full-screen function, I would like to be able to allow another program to get focus and have the Flash video stay full-screen.

I'm using Chrome  27.0.1453.110 with Adobe's implementation of Flash 11.2. I'm using 11.2 because the primary purpose of using Flash is Amazon's Instant Video.

Currently, whenever another program gains focus, the Flash full-screen restores back to what it was before. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being annoyed at this problem myself, and not liking how many of the extensions to accomplish this objective are so flaky or don't work on all sites, I've made my own extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maximize-flash/chihjmmmhbapnhemoopibkekbojilhge?hl=en

When you click on the icon it will maximize/restore the original size to the biggest flash object on the page.

Some things that this extension does that others don't are:

- Will keep playing the item inline where it is in the DOM, meaning that the video won't reload.  For some videos trying to reload the video won't work at all, and for others it will do annoying things such as cause you to have to watch the ad at the start of the video again.
- Will search through all iframes in the current site to find the flash object with the biggest area to maximize.
- Preserves aspect ratio of the video.
- Supports HTML 5 videos as well.
- Will resize the maximized video as you resize the browser window, allowing you to create custom video sizes for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer it, but my my workaround it is the zoom in to the video.

You can zoom in on the web page by hitting <kbd>"Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>++</kbd> on your keyboard. Likewise, you can zoom out by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>--</kbd>.

I am curious to see if other people have any workarounds/Hacks.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I found something a little better, where I can get the URI of the swf file from the page's source and load that directly into the address bar and maximize it. It's larger than it is embedded in the page but still has UI elements around it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Since this is very makeshift, I'd suggest the answer from shariat.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maximizeflash/lljjmflmcnaigbhnheldbdbplkbhngnl) for Chrome. It allows you to resize a webpage flash element to fit the Chrome window size, on the same page or in a new tab.